# Reading multiline standard input in J

Tags: io, j

Now I use this code to read data from standard input:

```
print =: 1!:2&2
read =: 1!:1[3

in =. (read-.LR)-.CR
```

But it returns just a sequence of numbers, e.g. input:

2
3
4
5

Output:

2345

Number of numbers is unknown, but each is in the separate line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When reading with (1!:1) you read a stream of characters. You have to manipulate the stream to get your desired input.

For example. If you want to enter a list of line separated integers, you would read the list, then split it by LF, remove LF and then convert to integer. You can achieve the first two steps using `cut (;._2)` and the conversion using `do (".)`:

```
in =: ".;._2 (1!:1) 3
```

If you want to enter a list of space separated integers, you would just use `do`, the splitting would be implied by the spaces:

```
in =: ". LF -.~ (1!:1) 3
```

trailing `LF` (if present) has to be removed before applying `".` because `do` can't convert special characters.